# In Kotlin Multiplatform, using gradle.kts, how do I determine the compilers used for targets like linuxX64, mingwX64, and mac/ios?

Tags: kotlin, native, multiplatform, cinterop

I need to know what compilers are being used so I can compile my C++ code with them.

I tried using the standard host compilers (for when the target == my host) and it did not work due to undefined standard library symbols.  I was able to find the compiler being used via a lucky guess (in ~/.konan/...) and it works fine.  But I'd rather not have to manually discover these compilers for every platform.  I'd rather get them out of the gradle build, similar to "android.ndkDirectory" for android targets.